# Select <span> out auf <span></span><a></a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, unit-testing

I'm testing a directive which cuts off text after 200 characters. It transforms this:

```
<span mw-text-collapse="long text long text long text
 long text long text long text long text long text long 
 text long text long text long text long text long text 
 long text long text long text long text long text long 
 text long text long text long text long text long text 
 long text long text long text long text long text long 
 text long text long text long text long text long text 
 long text long text long text long text long text long 
 text long text long text long text long text long text 
 long text long text long text long text long text long 
 text long text" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"></span>
```

to this:

```
 <span class="line-break ng-binding">
    long text long text long text long text long 
    text long text long text long text long text 
    long text long text long text long text long 
    text long text long text long text long text 
    long text long text ...
 </span>
 <a ng-if="showButton" ng-click="toggleLength()" style="cursor: pointer" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
    {{ showLessOrMore() | i18n }}
 </a>
```

In order to check whether there are really 200 characters **I need to select the span element only**. How can I do this? I tried `el.find('span')` but with no success.

This is my test:

```
describe('mwTextCollapse', function () {

  var longText = 'long text long text long text long text long text ' +
    'long text long text long text long text long text long text long text ' +
    'long text long text long text long text long text long text long text ' +
    'long text long text long text long text long text long text long text ' +
    'long text long text long text long text long text long text long text ' +
    'long text long text long text long text long text long text long text ' +
    'long text long text long text long text long text long text long text ' +
    'long text long text long text long text long text long text long text';


  fit('text should have a default length of 200 chars', function () {
    var textCollapse = '<span mw-text-collapse="' + longText + '"></span>';
    var el = $compile(textCollapse)(scope);
    scope.$digest();

    console.log(el.html());   
  });
});
```

The directive to test:

```
.directive('mwTextCollapse', function ($filter) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      mwTextCollapse: '@',
      length: '=',
      markdown: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'modules/ui/templates/mwComponents/mwTextCollapse.html',
    link: function (scope) {

      // set default length
      if( scope.length && typeof scope.length === 'number' ) {
        scope.defaultLength = scope.length;
      } else {
        scope.defaultLength = 200;
      }

      // set start length for filter
      scope.filterLength = scope.defaultLength;

      // apply filter length to text
      scope.text = function(){
        return $filter('reduceStringTo')(
          scope.mwTextCollapse, scope.filterLength
        );
      };

      // show Button if text is longer than desired
      scope.showButton = false;
      if( scope.mwTextCollapse.length > scope.defaultLength ) {
        scope.showButton = true;
      }

      // set button to "show more" or "show less"
      scope.showLessOrMore = function () {
        if( scope.filterLength === scope.defaultLength ){
          return 'common.showMore';
        } else {
          return 'common.showLess';
        }
      };

      // collapse/expand text by setting filter length
      scope.toggleLength = function () {
        if( scope.filterLength === scope.defaultLength ) {
          delete scope.filterLength;
        } else {
          scope.filterLength = scope.defaultLength;
        }
      };
    }
  };
})
```

I've tried dfsq solution:

```
 fit('text should have a default length of 200 chars', function () {
    var textCollapse = '<span mw-text-collapse="' + longText + '"></span>';
    var el = $compile(textCollapse)(scope);
    scope.$digest();

    var span = angular.element(el[0]);
    console.log(span.html());


  });
```

which still yields the `<a></a>` :(

```
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket wIMQX3-7dA2T5nIr11PI with id 86239756
LOG: '<!-- ngIf: markdown -->

<!-- ngIf: !markdown --><div ng-if="!markdown" class="ng-scope">
  <span class="line-break ng-binding">long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text ...</span>
  <!-- ngIf: showButton --><a ng-if="showButton" ng-click="toggleLength()" style="cursor: pointer" class="ng-binding ng-scope">{{ showLessOrMore() | i18n }}</a><!-- end ngIf: showButton -->
</div><!-- end ngIf: !markdown -->

'
```

Edit: Got it, correct selection would be

```
var span = angular.element(el[0].children[0].children[0]);
```

even better

```
var span = el.find('span').text();
```

Comment: Show `toggleLength()` function, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since directive compilation results into two sibling nodes, you should be able to grab span only by 0-index (it will be HTMLSpanElement):

```
var textCollapse = '<span mw-text-collapse="' + longText + '"></span>';
var el = $compile(textCollapse)(scope);
scope.$digest();

var span = angular.element(el[0].children[0]);
var link = angular.element(el[0].children[1]);

console.log(span.html());
```

Comment: tried your solution, but i'm still getting the `<a></a>`. see my updated question

Comment: almost, needs one more `children[0]` selector: `var span = angular.element(el[0].children[0].children[0]);`, but since you got me on the right track I'll select your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid Javascript altogether by adding the following CSS attribute:

```
.ng-scope {
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.ng-scope.show {
     text-overflow:clip;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp

Then just toggle the class "show" on the span when the toggle button is clicked.

Comment: that would cut off the text after a single line, wich is not what I want to achieve with this directive.